# Can the "People also ask" google snippet be used for keyword research?

Tags: seo, google, keywords

I tried running keywords I found under the "people also ask" google snippet. One was "How do you take the bitterness out of tea?". Since it's a snippet I assumed people search for this query, but two KW research tools (longtailpro and kwfinder) showed 0 monthly searches.

Does the "people also ask" snippet shows you answers to actual searches, or does it just shows answers to hypothetical queries which may not exist in the first place?

Comment: Uuuggghh! Freaking keywords again! Keywords is not how search works. Search engines do not match search terms nor do they need to be bludgeoned over the head with keywords. You first example is a perfect illustration for this. You provided a fully semantic example, "How do you take the bitterness out of tea?" All you need to do is answer this question. The people also ask section does give clues to other similar queies and content you may want to create. All you have to do is create competitive content on the topics that apply to your site. Create enough good content and you are golden!

Comment: @closetnoc so I shouldnt do KW research with longtailpro to assess the profitability of writing about one query over another?

Comment: My advise is to always cover any topic thoroughly. Since search changes each day, I do not like to look in the rear view mirror and try and guess what search will be tomorrow. This is impossible! Instead, I go for making any site a go to site for information. I do not do topic de jur. These are often behind the trend. I prefer to get out in front of trends by having the content already created. Again, the kw chase that SEOs advise is not how search works. Keywords is not how SEs work or even close to how they work. Cheers!!